# Is there a tool for reformatting C# code?

Tags: c#, code-formatting

I am looking for a (preferably) command-line tool that can reformat the C# source code on a directory tree. Ideally, I should be able to customize the formatting. Bonus points if the tool can be run on [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) (or Linux).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net) to reformat your code.  The formatting options it supports are still pretty limited, but it can process an entire directory and is a command-line tool. Also, NArrange runs under Mono.

Answer (score 4):

You could give [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) a try. It requires [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) to be installed though.

It's got a decent list of formatting options, and supports C and Java as well.

Comment: It doesn't work that well with C# though.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't command-line, Mono or Linux, but it's something: I've been using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (made by JetBrains) and it's rather good. It's a Visual Studio plugin, so I'm guessing it's not your cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Polystyle](http://www.polystyle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) and [csharp-mode](https://code.google.com/archive/p/csharpmode). One keystroke and the module is reformatted according to my desires.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See our [SD C# Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CSharpFormatter.html).  Uses a full C# parser and prettyprinter; it will not break your code.

EDIT: September, 2013:  Now runs on Windows and Linux.  Covers C# v5.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, check out http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It doesn't work that well with C# though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out astyle. I am sure the KDE guys use it, but the website said that it supports C#.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to second the ReSharper suggestion. I can't live without it.

The built-in reformatting is under ReSharper → *Tools* → *Cleanup Code* menu and is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at [this free Addin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c5664a7-a723-4ac1-9932-d840dfafd6d5) for Visual Studio 2010/2012 i recently wrote :)