# Is there an automatic code formatter for C#?

Tags: c#, formatting, build-automation

In my work I deal mostly with C# code nowadays, with a sprinkle of java from time to time. What I absolutely love about Eclipse (and I know people using it daily love it even more) is a sophisticated code formatter, able to mould code into any coding standard one might imagine. Is there such a tool for C#? Visual Studio code formatting (Crtl+K, Crtl+D) is subpar and StyleCop only checks the source without fixing it.

My dream tool would run from console (for easy inclusion in automated builds or pre-commit hooks and for execution on Linux + Mono), have text-file based configuration easy to store in a project repository and a graphical rule editor with preview - just like the Eclipse Code Formatter does.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For Visual Studio, take a look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper). It's an awesome tool and a definite must-have. Versions after 4.0 have the code formatting and clean-up feature that you are looking for. There's also [plugin integration with StyleCop](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/), including formatting settings file.

You'll probably want [Agent Smith plugin](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.AgentSmith/) as well, for spell-checking the identifiers and comments. ReSharper supports per-solution formatting setting files, which can be checked into version control system and shared by the whole team. The keyboard shortcut for code cleanup is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>.

In 'vanilla' Visual Studio, the current file can be automatically formatted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> formats the selected text.

As for a runs-everywhere command line tool to be used with commit hooks, try [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/). It's free, can process whole directories at once and runs on Mono as well as on Microsoft .NET.

Some people also use the [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) command line tool, although it requires Perl and works better with C/C++ code than with C#.

Comment: works well... and it does more than format code!

Answer (score 24):

The [.NET Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Foundation) just released their code formatting tool on GitHub

https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter

It uses the [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform) compiler services to parse project documents and convert them to their expected formatting conventions. They're applying this to some of the very old [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) code in order to make all the projects consistent.

Comment: Be sure to configure your own Editor Config file: http://editorconfig.org/

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter/releases

Comment: Can't get it to work, it just does nothing. And why does this tool want a project file anyway? How is formatting not a per-file job?

Comment: Their is also CSharpier https://github.com/belav/csharpier (inspired by Prettier)

Comment: Note that this tool seems to have been replaced by [`dotnet-format`](https://github.com/dotnet/format).

Answer (score 15):

Further to @Chris Karcher's answer - you can also automatically format the *whole document* by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

These formatting features work on a variety of file formats - it works wonders on ugly HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Another option: [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/);

- free
- console based (so good for commit hooks etc, but can still be used as an "External Tool" in VS)
- flexible config file

Comment: I haven't managed to use NArrange for code formatting (yet?). All it seemed to do was randomize the order of members in my source files based on basically arbitrary criteria such as access level or member type, but erroneous indentation and operator spacing within methods was left untouched. In fact, the NArrange docs even say "NArrange does not currently parse to the statement level of constructors, methods and properties" - if this means what I think it means, NArrange may be useful for code reorganization, but doesn't really do much formatting.

Answer (score 5):

For me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> maps to Find in Files. When I need to format code, I highlight it and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

I understand this doesn't really address automated formatting. I just wanted to clarify for those who may not know this feature even exists in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard only good things about [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper).  It's on my to-learn list.

Comment: But it costs USD 1000 per year?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sourceformat.com/

This tool is around (~30$). I tried it and it works nice (with multiple languages).

I like this tool the best because it doesn't check code file for correctness. I can post code snippets from the Internet and it will translate them correctly no matter if they are in missing parts of the code. Other tools I try complain in that cases. The tool can also be integrated easily into editors as it allows command line driving.

Other tools:

http://www.polystyle.com/index.jsp

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/ (open source)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but I use the [Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) plugin for R# to do this. Unfortunately, R# isn't free.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [Microsoft StyleCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/)

Comment: Or its replacement https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this (found it through Google). It might work. http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CSharpFormatter.html. It's fairly cheap at USD50, but a trial is not available.

Answer (score 1):

See this previous question:

[Is there any tool for reformatting C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253/is-there-any-tool-for-reformatting-c-code)

Searching for [c#] astyle shows up some more previous questions too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could be interested in [this free Addin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c5664a7-a723-4ac1-9932-d840dfafd6d5) for Visual Studio 2010/2012.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open source code formatting tool which has amazing features

[CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/)

Comment: this addon is not able to formatting the code, only comments formatting is supported

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it online, have a [freecodeformat](http://www.freecodeformat.com/c-format.php).