# C# Code Formatter for Linux and/or MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, formatting, mono

MonoDevelop 1.0 doesn't appear to have a code-formatter like Eclipse does for Java.  Is there a preferred shell script (or MonoDevelop add-in?) that you've found to work well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101/is-there-an-automatic-code-formatter-for-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, source code formatting in MonoDevelop is marked as a future enhancement:
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=321946

In the meantime, you may want to check out Artistic Style for C# formatting:
http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

I'm planning to see how this might be wired up as an external tool within MonoDevelop.  If I get to that, I will edit my answer with the information. **UPDATE: I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so I'll make one here: Nice job, Dustin, and patch for MonoDevelop too :-)  I wonder how recent the version is that is included with Ubuntu... Either way, I'm glad you found something that works for you.**

Comment: Awesome -- I just realized AStyle is available in Ubuntu as a package.

Comment: I'm able to add "astyle" as an external tool in MonoDevelop, but it barfs when trying to use the variable substitutions.  It appears MonoDevelop is not expanding the ${itemPath} like it is supposed to -- perhaps it is quoting it?  I'm going to take a look at the source now to see.

Comment: Well, I was able to patch MonoDevelop to properly use astyle as an external tool.  I'll look for existing bug reports and submit a new bug if necessary along with the patch.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Brandon.  I submitted a patch to MonoDevelop.  The issue with MonoDevelop add-ins is that there is a mono compiler bug that doesn't handle anonymous delegates correctly. (bug report: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=394347)

The patch/workaround is to just cast the anonymous delegate to the proper delegate type.  (bug report & patch: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=369538)

I'm running with the patched version now and am able to execute AStyle on the currently edited document by simply creating a new External Tool setting with the following settings:

TITLE: A_Style (put in an underscore <kbd>_</kbd> to enable hotkeys)
COMMAND: astyle
ARGUMENTS: ${ItemPath}

Then, just execute it using Tools->AStyle (or <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>)

9/25/08 Edit -- I just put up a blog posting on how to patch MonoDevelop 1.0 and get it working with AStyle: http://dustinbreese.blogspot.com/2008/09/auto-formatting-code-in-monodevelop-10.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice programming exercise to write your own formatter . I wrote one for C++ , and it was a nice challenge . You could learn a lot by writing it :)